# primusrun: Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: nvidia, antergos, bumblebee, optimus

I've just installed antergos with gnome de and bumblebee on asus R542 laptop.

When I run `primusrun glxspheres64` it fails and logs this:

```
$ primusrun glxspheres64
Polygons in scene: 62464 (61 spheres * 1024 polys/spheres)
Visual ID of window: 0x130
Context is Direct
OpenGL Renderer: GeForce 930MX/PCIe/SSE2
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

`optirun glxspheres64` is ok:

```
$ optirun -c yuv glxspheres64
Polygons in scene: 62464 (61 spheres * 1024 polys/spheres)
Visual ID of window: 0x21
Context is Direct
OpenGL Renderer: GeForce 930MX/PCIe/SSE2
103.963006 frames/sec - 116.022715 Mpixels/sec
104.108801 frames/sec - 116.185422 Mpixels/sec
```

Comment: Usually when there's a segfault one should collect a backtrace in a debugger, which may help the developers track down the issue.

Comment: @thrig so what should I do?

Comment: You mention you "checked out other forums" -- which ones, and what advice have you tried so far?  Arch (on which Antergos is based) has an open bug about this: https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/58933

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem here. Just downgrade mesa to 18.0.4.
I use Arch, so I did:
 `pacman -U /var/cache/pacman/pkg/mesa-18.0.4-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz`

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if the problem is in mesa, xserver or primus, but here's the upstream bug report: https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=106910 and here's a simple workaround:

```
export LIBGL_DRI3_DISABLE=1
primusrun glxgears
```